# How to send response email to user on form submit PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, email, submit

I have a rather basic php form that submits on the same page it is called "registration.php". I have it set to collect the form data, store it in the $to, $subject and $body variables then I call the mail() method to send off an email to myself.

please see code below ( Don't worry! there is a question comin' right up! ):

```
<?php
ob_start(); //output buffering because I like it.

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // Process the form
  $message = "Thank you for registering! We will respond to your request shortly";
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  $comments = $_POST['userComment'];
  $date = gmdate("M d Y");


$to = "myemail@outlook.com";
$subject = "Registration Submission";
$body = " Date: $date \n Registrant Name/Name's: $name \n Registrant E-mail: $email \n \n User Comments: \n $comments \n \n";

mail($to,$subject,$body);

}

?>
```

```html
<form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" action="registration.php" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="name"><strong>Registrant Name / Names</strong></label></td>
                        <td><input required='required' type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="email"><strong>Registrant E-mail</strong></label></td>
                        <td><input required='required' type="email" maxlength="40" id="email" name="email" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="subject"><strong>Registrant Address</strong></label></td>
                        <td><input required='required' type="text" maxlength="100"  id="address" name="address" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Message&#58;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="textAreaInput" colspan="2"><textarea  rows="3" id="userComment" name="userComment" placeholder="Let us know your thoughts!"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

What I want to know is Can I send a custom response email to the users collected $email with a custom message using just php? can I send other variables through the mail() method? like $to2, $subject2, $body2 or must they be named $to, $subject & $body when passed?

I have a working solution using PHPMailer found here:

```
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
```

I am just curious as to weither or not there is an easy process using PHP that wouldn't rely on a required library.

Comment: the variables can be named anything

Comment: oh well im just feelin completely silly right now then. so I can just declare $to2, $subject2, $body2 in mail($to2, $subject2, $body2) and put in the users info. neato Ill give it a go

Comment: the funnest and most educational part of programming is experimenting ;-) ENJOY!!

Answer (score 0):

I think all you have to do is

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$body)){
   mail($email,"Thanks!!","Thank you very much for registering!!!")
}
```